# Upgrade to 2.3.1 from 2.2.7 fails on setup:upgrade

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1

I am trying to upgrade a local copy of our site from 2.2.7 to 2.3.1 and have got through the composer cli pain and am now on the bin/magento setup:upgrade step.  It gets all of the way to Running data recurring... and then spits out the following

```
The XML in file "/var/www/mag/vendor/faonni/module-indexer-url-rewrite/etc/mview.xml" is invalid:
Element 'subscriptions': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( table ).
Line: 12

Element 'subscriptions': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( table ).
Line: 15

Element 'subscriptions': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( table ).
Line: 18

Verify the XML and try again.
```

So I attempted to remove the faonni/module-indexer-url-rewrite module via composer and then require it again to see if if was an old version hanging around.  No luck same error. Any ideas?

EDIT:-
To confirm I was following the guide at [CLI Upgrade](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

Comment: have you used the pre-composer script? the upgrade to 2.3.1 is not just inceasing version and run a setup:upgrade

Comment: No I was doing this all via CLI, so that I can take care of some of the extension we have that did not play nice

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by removing the module completely.  Now just need to find a replacement.